# Unable to get ANSI colors in PHP CLI without passing --ansi

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, ansi-escape

I am using CentOS 7 with PHP 7.0

`TERM=xterm-256color`

I do have a colorized prompt and ls colors and if I pass `--ansi` then it does show up colored but I do not want to always have to add `--ansi`

The two specific items I am using is `composer` and `app/console` from Symfony 2.8

Comment: Do you want to color the ouptut of a Symfony2 console command?

Comment: Yes. If do `app/console --ansi` I get what I am wanting but I want to do it without having to add `--ansi`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in a comment on another question.

https://serverfault.com/questions/591105/centos-colors-in-php-cli-applications#comment-698025

Apparently, it requires the package `php-posix` which then CentOS displays as `php-process` when it installs it.

All I did was do `yum install php-posix` and composer now shows up with ansi colors by default.